# print a string on two different lines

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, a86

I am trying to get my program to display a string on two different lines.

This is a .com program and I am using A86 assembler.

```
jmp start               ; This will start the program

;============================

  msg   db  "Hello Word.$"      ; A string variable 
  msg   db  "Michael J. Crawley$"   ; A string variable with a value.

;============================

start:

  mov ah,09             ; subfunction 9 output a string

  mov dx,offset msg         ; DX for the string

  int 21h               ; Output the message

  int 21h               ; Output the message

exit:

  mov ah,4ch
  mov al,00             ; Exit code 

  int 21h               ; End program
```

Comment: What's the issue you are having with the code? Does it 'compile'? Are you getting weird output? Best to add this to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are your specific problems:

- You define `msg` twice (a86 will barf on that).
- You call int21 fn9 with the *same* value of msg so you're not printing the two messages out, just two copies of the first.
- You don't have a newline character in either message so they'll abut each other rather than be on separate lines.

The solutions to those points (without providing the actual code).

- Label the second message as `msg2`.
- Load `msg2` into dx before calling int21 for the second time.
- Change the messages to put a newline before the '$' symbol (or at least the first one).

---

*Update:* Since some other helpful soul has already provided source, here's my solution. I would suggest you *learn* from this and modify your own code to do a similar thing. If you copy it verbatim from a public site for classwork, you'll almost certainly be caught out for plagiarism:

```
         jmp start                   ; This will start the program

msg      db  "Hello Word.",0a,"$"    ; A string variable .
msg2     db  "Michael J. Crawley$"   ; A string variable with a value.

start:   mov ah,09                   ; subfunction 9 output a string
         mov dx,offset msg           ; DX for the string
         int 21h                     ; Output the message
         mov dx,offset msg2          ; DX for the string
         int 21h                     ; Output the message
exit:
         mov ah,4ch
         mov al,00                   ; Exit code 
         int 21h                     ; End program
```

This outputs:

```
Hello Word.
Michael J. Crawley
```

Comment: Don't DOS int21 calls return a result code in AX as well so it would have to be reloaded before the 2nd call?  Or did DOS just set the carry flag to indicate an error.

Comment: @Michael, not fn9, it returns nothing.

Comment: No... I am not a copy paste kind of guy I actually want to learn this. 

I will try it.

Comment: 0a is the placement of the string?

Comment: @Mike, 0a is the hex code for a newline (ASCII 10) character. int21/fn9 will intepret this as a request to drop down to the start of a new line.

Comment: Be aware, you might also need a `0Dh` byte along with the `0Ah` byte to do a complete new line and carriage return

Answer (score 1):

Two definitions of msg?

Comment: I am not sure I understand.  Should I remove one.... 

 db  "Michael J. Crawley$"   ; A string variable with a value.

Comment: @Mike: No, they each need unique names. You could replace the first "msg" with "msg1", and the second with "msg2".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with a86, but with NASM & MASM you need an "org 100h" assembler directive at the beginning of a com program.  The way it is now, offset msg is 0x2, and that'll try to print from the second byte of the program segment prefix (a 16 bit word that holds the segment of the top of memory available to you).

Comment: This is why a86 is so good and why Harald is so rightly arrogant :-) It will assemble a file without _any_ of the gumpff required by other assemblers - I always hated masm and it's requirement that I had to provide 25 lines of administrivia just to do a 5-line hello world program. Turbo Assembler took away a lot of that but a86 goes all the way.