# How can I write 'Hello world' in C without using any function?

Tags: c, assembly

I found the way to do it on quora but I can not understand it.

```
You can achieve this using opcodes.....

const int main[] = {  -443987883, 440, 113408, -1922629632,  4149, 899584, 84869120, 15544,  266023168, 1818576901, 1461743468, 1684828783,  -1017312735};
Now follow below steps....
Save that in hello.c
then gcc -o hello hello.c
then ./hello
Hola..... Hello World!
```

Op-codes will be specific for specific hardware and controller based on architecture of it. If I understood correctly then op-codes will be different for different hardware and platforms. So this is not a generic solution. However I tried to compiler it on IDEone & it gives run time error. Is there any generic solution?

[Similar question on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280998/hello-world-function-without-using-c-printf)

Comment: Please, SO is no code-golf. Try it there. :)

Comment: Disassemble the binary and you will see.

Comment: That code is not a valid C program in the first place.  It may work on certain platforms, but not all.

Comment: Whatt grows on Quora should stay on Quora.

Comment: Is there any other solution? Why down votes?

Comment: The answer is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764796/why-does-declaring-main-as-an-array-compile/34765279#34765279).

Answer (score 5):

In C, the `main` function is the entrypoint into your program. In the program binary, the machine code into which the function is compile will get placed in the `.text` section of the binary as well as the location of the `main` function in the symbol table.

In the above code we create a constant array with the same `main` symbol name. Since the array is constant, this will also get placed in the `.text` section of the binary. And since any code in the `.text` section is executable, there is nothing to stop the opcodes in the main array getting executed.